# Subscriber/Observer pattern in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is it possible to use the subscriber/observer pattern in Ember.js? For example, view A and view B both listens to changes inside a model C. This requires model C to be able to trigger custom events. I've been trying to figure out how to make a model trigger event in Ember.js but no luck so far.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the feature you are looking for is called "Bindings" in Ember.js.

There are tons of examples on the homepage that describe how to do what you are suggesting, but here is a quick recap:

```
window.MyApp = Ember.Application.create();

MyApp.MyModel = Ember.Object.create({
  myProperty: "Hello World!",

  goodbye: function() {
    this.set("myProperty", "Goodbye!");
  })
});

MyApp.modelInstance = MyApp.MyModel.create();
```

Now create your two views inside your `<body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  View1: <b>{{MyApp.modelInstance.myProperty}}</b>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  View2: <b>{{MyApp.modelInstance.myProperty}}</b>
</script>
```

Now the page should render and you'll see both views say "Hello World!". Open up the console and type

```
MyApp.modelInstance.goodbye();
```

And you'll see your views change to say "Goodbye!".

The views automatically create Bindings to `MyApp.modelInstance.myProperty` by using the double curly braces, but you can create bindings in a variety of ways. Whenever the value of `myProperty` changes, all of the bindings will be automatically updated. Note, however, that you must call `set("myProperty", "something new")` so that Ember knows to update the bindings for you; it won't fire any change events if you just say `myProperty = "something new"`.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Sproutcore, that is what bindings are for.

If you have a model

```
App.Person = SC.Object.extend({
   name: 'Bruce Banner'
});
```

You would then have a controller such as

`App.personController = SC.ObjectController.create();`

You could then set the content on the controller

`App.personController.set('content', somePerson);`

Now, any view can bind to the data on the model object.

```
SC.LabelView = SC.LabelView.extend({
...
    valueBinding: 'App.personController.name'
})
```

So if you ever change the name

`somePerson.set('name', 'Chris');`

The view will update automatically.

Comment: Actually what I was looking for is for view A to be able to talk to view B through model C. For example, if view A is a list of items, clicking on a keyword will trigger an event in model C. Then view B listens to model C's event, view B will handle the event accordingly.

Comment: what is the model in this case?  It would help to have some example code. Model objects are supposed to represent data in your app (loaded from a server).  What you are talking about seems to be about app and view state.